# Horizontal Pager compose page calling twice

Tags: android-jetpack-compose-ui

Horizontal Pager compose page twice

```
HorizontalPager(                 
    count = tabs.size,                 
    state = pagerState) { page ->
                       when (tabs[page]) {                     
                           PAGE1 -> // Page1 content -- calling twice                            
                           PAGE2 -> //Page2 content -- calling twice               
                           }
                        }
```

My expectation is to call PAGE1 and PAGE2 only once when we change the tab

Comment: Did you figure this one?